# the definition of continuity from a single to multi variable case

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In a single variable case, we know that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=f(c).$$

My question is does this property still holds in a multi variable case. For example, let $f:D\subset R^4 \to R$, and $(a,b,c,d)$ be a cluster point of $D$. Then, $f$ is continuous at $(a,b,c,d)$ if and only if$$\lim_{(x,y,z,s)\to(a,b,c,d)}f(x,y,z,s)=f(a,b,c,d).$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes that is the proper definition for continuity at a point for multivariate functions.

Comment: Then, if $f:D\to R^2$ defined by $f=(f_1, f_2).$ Should I compute two limit to prove that it is continuous? For example, $\lim f_1 = f_1$ and $\lim f_2 = f_2 $.

Comment: Yes you would need continuity in each component to have continuity.

Comment: Note that you can prove any continuity statement about multivariable functions using norms $\|.\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ in place of absolute values.